# how to differentiate between isCellEditable() being called due to a user click or due to column dragging

Tags: jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a JTable with custom  editor and renderer. I have my table model also.I want to instantiate an special input window when user clicks on a cell of an specific column. I have written the logic in isCellEditable() but now the problem is that when I click on any cell of that specific column then the input window pops up then I input my value until now every thing works fine. But now when I try to shift the column position by dragging the header then again isCellEditable() is called and without any user click on the cell of that specific column the window pops up. 
Kindly suggest how to differentiate between a user click and column dragging.

Regards 
Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I was not able to find an answer to my question but I got my purpose solved. I wrote all my logic of instantiating the complex window in my class: CustomCellRenderer , getTableCellEditorComponent(). My  CustomCellRenderer  extends DefaultCellEditor. The only mistake I was doing was calling the setValueAt() of the table model in the logic. Later I found that I had the option of setting the value of the component in the getTableCellEditorComponent() it self. Later the  same component is returned.